# Como exercer print na interface gráfica?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interface, pyqt-5

Preciso que o resultado da função `print((randint(0,700))` apareça no rótulo (label) da janela de meu programa (criado com o Qt Designer do próprio Py), e não no interpretador, mas só conheço o comando `interface.label.setText("")` que só mostra o texto colocado, nada mais.
Essa é a programação:

```
    from random import randint
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
janela=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
interface=uic.loadUi ("hello_interface.ui")
def PRINT():
    **interface.label.setText("print(randint(0,700))")**
interface.pushButton.clicked.connect(PRINT)
interface.show()
janela.exec
```

Só preciso que apareça o resultado do `print(randint)` em vez do texto do código, por favor!

Comment: Não bastaria fazer `interface.label.setText(randint(0,700))`?

Comment: só precisa converter pra string -  `.setText(str(randint(0, 700))` ou `.setText(f"{randint(0, 700)}")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O print em Python 3 é apenas uma função - embora muito usada, que converte os parâmetros passados em sequência para strings, e escreve essas strings no arquivo `sys.stdout` por padrão.

Quando usamos uma interface gráfica, não adianta colocar os conteúdos desejados nem no sys.stdout, e em geral nem em outro arquivo - e sim, chamar métodos específicos dos componentes da interface gráfica passando o texto que desejamos exibir como uma string. Não faz sentido tentar usar o `print`, que sequer retorna um valor.

No seu programa, se o método que apresenta a string no local desejado é o `interface.label.setText(...)`, tudo  o que você precisa fazer é passar o que deseja exibir como texto (string) para ele. Uma das formas de fazer essa conversão no Python é usar a chamada `str(...)`  - que vai usar os mecanismos internos de cada objeto para obter sua representação em texto.

Então, provavelmente, tudo o que você precisa aí é:

```py
def PRINT():
    interface.label.setText(str(randint(0,700)))
```

(Provavelmente por que sem os outros arquivos do projeto, e etc...não tenho como afirmar que esse é o método correto para exibir o texto no local desejado)